# How to replace all parts of a string by regex that stats with a \ and ends with \ or space or {?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, space

I want to create an RTF reader, and I want to get the plain text part. But I can't "delete" the commands from the incoming string 's'...

```
var plain = s.replace(/\\.*(\\|\s|{){1}/g,"");
```

Comment: a sample input and expected output would be better.

Comment: {\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard
This is some {\b bold} t�xt.\par
}

Comment: A command starts with a \ and ends with \ or space or {

Comment: you mean this `\\.*?(\\|\s|{)`

Comment: have you looked to see if there are any javascipt RTF parsing libraries already out there?  I think what you really want here is a parsing solution, not a regex one.

Comment: In addition to making the the `.*` non-greedy with `.*?`, the `{1}` is redundant and you need to escape `{` as `\{`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
\\[^\\\s]*(?=\s|\\|{)
```

Try this. see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/59